# select from table where column = anything

Tags: sql, sql-server

A simplified example of what I need:

Table 'Transport' has 2 columns; 'Vehicle' and 'Colour'.  User can filter records by either a vehicle, a colour, or both.

```
variable vehicle_choice = user_selected_vehicle (selected from a dropdown for example)
variable colour_choice = user_selected_colour

If user_selected_vehicle = nothing selected Then
    vehicle_choice = *
End if

If user_selected_colour = nothing selected Then
    colour_choice = *
End if

Select query = ("Select * From Transport Where Vehicle = vehicle_choice And Colour = colour_choice")
```

So if the user wanted a 'red' 'bus' the query would look like:

```
("Select * From Transport Where Vehicle = 'bus' And Colour = 'red'")
```

Which would be fine and find the record if it existed.

But, if the user wanted all vehicles that were yellow the query would look like:

```
("Select * From Transport Where Vehicle = * and Colour = 'yellow'")
```

Clearly this is all in a made up syntax but this is what I want, is it possible in SQL?  (Using MS SQL Server 2008)

Comment: Erland Sommarskog wrote a pretty decent article titled [Dynamic search conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) which covers most scenarios.

Comment: Also, I would recommend reading [this article](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) on 'SQL in the Wild' blog.

Comment: I am up for learning more and will certainly take a look at these articles, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two typical ways to solve this.  Assume that the user input is in the variables `@vehicle` and `@colour`:

```
where (vehicle = @vehicle or @vehicle is null) and
      (colour = @colour or @colour is null)
```

The problem with this approach is the use of indexes.  Indexing strategies have a hard time with `or`.  So, if you are constructing the query dynamically, then it is better to only add the clauses you want:

```
@where = '1 = 1' +
         (case when @vehicle is not null then ' and vehicle = @vehicle' else '' end) +
         (case when @colour is not null then ' and colour = @colour' else '' end);
```

Comment: Ah, this makes sense.  I will try now and get back.

Comment: OK this works fine and is just what I need.  Many thanks.  Will accept shortly.

Answer (score 2):

You can prepare 2nd query

```
("Select * From Transport Where Vehicle = * and Colour = 'yellow'")
```

to this

```
("Select * From Transport Where Vehicle = Vehicle and Colour = 'yellow'")
```

It's only idea how to solve your problem.

Comment: My problem is that 'column = *' doesn't work.  I need to know what the proper syntax is for 'column can equal anything'  Would that mean column = column?

Comment: @Ryan I gave you solution above :)

Comment: wow, this is a very elegant solution, much better than other 3 answers (y)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like

```
("Select * From Transport Where Vehicle like '%' and Colour = 'yellow'")
```

Comment: This also seems to work and is a simple solution.  I would just need to change the query so that all column parameters were 'like' instead of '=' and change null value to '%'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. it is possible.just modify your query like this:

suppose your dropdown parameter is:

```
ddl1.val -- for transport
ddl2.val -- for color
```

now suppose your default ddl values is '0' or whatever for 'select all' option.now your query will be:

```
 Select * From Transport Where (Vehicle = ddl1.val or ddl1.val='0') and
(Colour = ddl2.val or ddl2.val='0')
```

alternate way to do this:

```
Select * From Transport Where Vehicle like '%' and Colour = 'color_selected'
```

let me know if u want any other clarification regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @vehicle_choice nvarchar(255)
declare @colour_choice nvarchar(255)
set @colour_choice = 'bus'
set @colour_choice = 'blue'

Select * From Transport 
    where 1= 1 
    and Vehicle like (case when @vehicle_choice Is null or @vehicle_choice = '' then '%' else @vehicle_choice end)
    and Colour like (case when @colour_choice Is null or @colour_choice = '' then '%' else @colour_choice end)
```